# How do I render vertical victory native legend to the right of chart?

Tags: legend, victory-charts

I have the following code and the associated result. However, my goal is to render the pie chart to the left and the legend to the right. Sometimes, my categories are a lot, so I would like to make the legend scrollable.

In summary, what I need help with is displaying the two with 50-50 split of the screen

```
export default () => {
  const { Layout } = useTheme()

  return <View style={Layout.rowCenter}>
    <VictoryContainer width={400} height={400} style={{ padding: 10 }}>
      <VictoryLegend
        standalone={false}
        centerTitle
        orientation="horizontal"
        style={{ labels: { fontSize: 20, fill: "white" } }}
        gutter={20}
        width={400}
        colorScale={colorScale || ["tomato", "lightgreen", "gold", "cyan", "navy", 'teal', 'magenta', 'green', 'orange', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'purple']}

        data={[
          { name: "one" },
          { name: "Two", },
          { name: "Three", },
          { name: "four", },
          { name: "five", }
        ]}
      />
      <VictoryPie
        standalone={false}
        margin={{
          top: 20
        }}
        width={400}
        height={400}
        colorScale={colorScale || ["tomato", "lightgreen", "gold", "cyan", "navy", 'teal', 'magenta', 'green', 'orange', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'purple']}
        labels={() => null}
        data={[
          { x: "one", y: 35 },
          { x: "Two", y: 40 },
          { x: "Three", y: 25 },
          { x: "four", y: 55 },
          { x: "five", y: 55 }
        ]}
      />
    </VictoryContainer>
  </View>
}
```

[image: Victory native bar chart with legend]

Answer (score 0):

use react native svg and adjust the height, width and distance from left and right using `viewBox` prop of react native svg, this way we can arrange and display the items in 50-50 split of the screen. Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).